# How to filter forms in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, filter

I am trying to make a rating system with django. So, I have:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Salesman(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region,
                               related_name='region',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Rating(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1,6)]
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Salesman,
                                 related_name='salesman',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region,
                               related_name='regions',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False)
    sent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rating}"
```

It is my model. In the first page user should select the region and then form should be opened with salesman, phone and rating fields. And salesman fields must show those salesmen who work in the selected region.

My forms.py is here:

```
class RateAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        exclude = ('region',)
    def __init__(self, region=None, **kwargs):
        super(RateAddForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if region:
            self.fields['salesman'].queryset = Salesman.objects.filter(region=region)
```

But still it shows me all salesmen regardless of their region.

My views.py is here, I can't take region, where should I add a region correctly?:

```
def report_add(request, region_slug):
    region = get_object_or_404(Region, slug=region_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RateAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = "Thanks!"
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(message)
        else:
            form = RateAddForm()
    else:
        form = RateAddForm(request.POST)
    return render(request,
                  'account/report.html',
                  {'form': form})
```

Are there anything I missed or would you suggest any good method? Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: You don't pass `region` to your form in the view, how does the view know the region?